# Can't load hidden class with VarHandle

Tags: java, jvm, methodhandle, varhandle

I am trying to load a class as a hidden class in Java, but run into a VerifyError.   The class uses a VarHandle, which has a `PolymorphicSignature`.  I believe the error is implying that the polymorphic call is using the non-hidden class, but it's not obvious to me what to do to fix it.  What is the correct way to define hidden classes that contain calls to MethodHandles or VarHandles?

```java
package foo;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class HiddenClassTest {

  @Test
  public void loadHidden() throws Exception {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup;
    try (var is = IntThing.class.getResourceAsStream("HiddenClassTest$IntThing.class")) {
      lookup =
          MethodHandles.lookup().defineHiddenClass(is.readAllBytes(), true);
    }
    var instance =
        lookup.lookupClass()
            .asSubclass(IntUnaryOperator.class)
            .getConstructor()
            .newInstance();
    System.out.println(instance.applyAsInt(12));
    System.out.println(instance.applyAsInt(24));
  }

  static final class IntThing implements IntUnaryOperator {
    static final VarHandle IDX;

    static {
      try {
        IDX = MethodHandles.lookup().findVarHandle(IntThing.class, "idx", int.class);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

    private int idx;

    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(int newIdx) {
      int oldIdx = (int) IDX.getOpaque(this);
      IDX.setOpaque(this, newIdx);
      return oldIdx;
    }
  }
}
```

The error:

```
Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing+0x0000000800d38c00.applyAsInt(I)I @4: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing+0x0000000800d38c00' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing+0x0000000800d38c00', integer }
    stack: { 'java/lang/invoke/VarHandle', 'foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing+0x0000000800d38c00' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 072a b600 0d3d b200 072a 1bb6 0013
    0000010: 1cac                                   

java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing+0x0000000800d38c00.applyAsInt(I)I @4: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing+0x0000000800d38c00' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing+0x0000000800d38c00', integer }
    stack: { 'java/lang/invoke/VarHandle', 'foo/HiddenClassTest$IntThing+0x0000000800d38c00' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 072a b600 0d3d b200 072a 1bb6 0013
    0000010: 1cac                                   

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2307)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassDefiner.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:2439)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassDefiner.defineClassAsLookup(MethodHandles.java:2420)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineHiddenClass(MethodHandles.java:2127)
    at foo.HiddenClassTest.loadHidden(HiddenClassTest.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: this is because of the polymorphic signature where `this` results in a reference to a different class in the signature. The workaround is to explicitly cast `this` to `Object` to force `Ljava/lang/Object;` in the signature instead of `LHiddenClassTest$IntThing;`

```
int oldIdx = (int) IDX.getOpaque((Object) this);
IDX.setOpaque((Object) this, newIdx);
return oldIdx;
```

Comment: Does this cause extra work for the VM?  Phrased differently, are there any downsides to always casting to Object?

Comment: @CarlMastrangelo Not in this case. There is a class cast inside `getOpaque` that verifies that the passed argument matches the receiver type of the VarHandle, but HotSpot is smart enough to recognize a redundant cast and eliminate it.

Answer (score 4):

As you have found, a hidden class can not be referenced by name from byte code. It can only be referenced through the `this_class` constant pool entry. This excludes use from descriptor strings though.

As [apangin says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75795843/3699139), you could explicitly cast the `this` argument to `Object` to avoid the class name from appearing in the descriptor.

If you want to avoid the inexact invocation that results from this, you could further convert the VarHandle into a set of MethodHandles for which the first parameter is erased to `Object`, and then invoke those with an exact call:

```
  static final class IntThing implements IntUnaryOperator {
    static final MethodHandle IDX_GET;
    static final MethodHandle IDX_SET;

    static {
      try {
        VarHandle VH_idx = MethodHandles.lookup().findVarHandle(IntThing.class, "idx", int.class);
        IDX_GET = VH_idx.toMethodHandle(VarHandle.AccessMode.GET_OPAQUE).asType(MethodType.methodType(int.class, Object.class));
        IDX_SET = VH_idx.toMethodHandle(VarHandle.AccessMode.SET_OPAQUE).asType(MethodType.methodType(void.class, Object.class, int.class));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

    private int idx;
    
    private int getIdx() {
      try {
        return (int) IDX_GET.invokeExact((Object) this);
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
      }
    }
    
    private void setIdx(int value) {
      try {
        IDX_SET.invokeExact((Object) this, value);
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(int newIdx) {
      int oldIdx = getIdx();
      setIdx(newIdx);
      return oldIdx;
    }
  }
```